# A curious sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to enumerate the next $\Delta_{ij}$ for $0\leq i<j\leq n\in\mathbb{N}$ as follows. 
$$\Delta_{01}=X_0$$
$$ \Delta_{02}=X_1,$$
$$\vdots 
$$
$$\Delta_{0n}=X_{n-1},$$
$$\Delta_{12}=X_{n},$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\Delta_{1n}=X_{2n-2},$$
$$\Delta_{23}=X_{2n-1},$$
$$\vdots$$
But I cannot get an explicit expression in order to write $\Delta_{ij}=X_{f(i,j)}$. Any ideas?

Comment: $\Delta_{ij} = X_{i n + j - i -1}$? Is it typo $\Delta_{23}$?

Comment: Nope, $i<j$, so after $\Delta_{1n}$ must go $\Delta_{23}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{cases}
i=0 &j-1 \\
i=1 & n+j-2 \\
i=2 & n+(n-1)+j-3 \\
i=3 & n+(n-1)+(n-2)+j-4 \\
... \\
i=k & n+(n-1)+...+(n-k+1)+j-k-1\\
\end{cases}$

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{u=0}^{k-1} n-u=nk-\sum\limits_{u=0}^{k-1} u=nk-\frac{(k-1)k}2$

> $f(i,j)=ni-\frac{i(i-1)}2+j-i-1$